# How to formulate QUBO as summation quadratic and linear parts of K-graph coloring problem?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, adiabatic-model, qubo

While trying to understand the graph coloring problem with VQE using the [QUBO Formulation](https://leeds-faculty.colorado.edu/glover/Quantum%20Bridge%20Analytics%20I%20-%20QBA%20Part%201.pdf) mentioned section "5.2 Graph Coloring". Mentioned article prepared the QUBO directly in to matrix form as shown below. But would like to achieve through the python code.

[image: QUBO Matrix]

My query:
**What shall be the initial matrix we need to consider? ex: all zero or all one's**

I am assuming shall look like **linear_term * x + xT * qudratic_term * x**. if there is better approach please do share.

I am able to get solution with the hard coded matrix as mentioned in the paper using VQE. But i want to try with the python code for the matrix part.

And graph part as shown below

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Please share the hints or reference for further explore.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: not able to delete the post due to a non registered user. So deleted the content.. Thanks for replying

Comment: @Ket why do you want to delete the post?